Returning static constexpr vector from const ref function
Is this valid code with well defined behavior?
I cannot get it to compile under MSVC 19.41.34123.0 which is a bit strange since constexpr vectors should be supported in that MSVC version according to cppreference. However it compiles just fine using GCC 13.2.0. Is it ok to do this though? And if it is ok, would this be preferred over just normal static const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> empty or does it even matter?
const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>& MyClass::getThing(int key) const
{
    auto it = m_map.find(key);
    if (it != m_map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    static constexpr std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> empty;
    return empty;
}


Can you post a [mre]? What is Bar? What error is raising?

error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant: (sub-)object points to memory which was heap allocated during constant evaluation
That's the MSVC error. However that's not really the issue, i'm more interested to know whether it is a good idea to define the empty vector as constexpr at all.

std::vector isn't guaranteed to work as a constexpr variable. There should be many duplicates of this question here. Replace constexpr with const.

Please [edit] the question and add the error message to there. You also should understand that constexpr-ness of the expression depends on Bar that is not shown.

you should probably use std::optional rather than creating dummy objects

@3CxEZiVlQ It is constexpr since C++20, but that doesn't matter, because it may perform heap allocation, which then makes the initialization not a constant expression. (This is not currently specified nicely, but that is the result.)

@user17732522 Your are not right, the code is valid in C++23, I mentioned C++23 in this context. What you are talking about is true in C++20.

@3CxEZiVlQ What C++23 change makes this valid?

Can't replicate even in C++20 https://godbolt.org/z/M7n8jocno. We need a [mre].

The dupe was wrong. The question is about static constexpr std::vector. The issue may be in Bar that is not shown.

@3CxEZiVlQ I'm having issues reproducing the MSVC error on godbolt as well. When i compile locally using version MSVC 19.32.31329.0 it compiles just fine. However when i push to github and use their latest image Windows CI Actions where MSVC 19.41.34123.0 is installed i get the above mentioned error. Building with cmake CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20.

@3CxEZiVlQ The static doesn't change anything. Unfortunately it is currently not clearly specified when exactly the initialization must fail as constant expression, but it is not generally guaranteed to succeed because the initialization may perform non-transient dynamic allocation as explained in the linked duplicate. The exact behavior depends on the standard library implementation and may change without notice or e.g. with compiler switches for library debugging, etc.

At best one could argue that the default constructor is noexcept so that it can't safely allocate without exception handling, but in a constant expression context the compiler knows that dynamic allocation will succeed, so it could do the allocation without need to throw and catch std::bad_alloc.

Depends on compiler.
Here's an idea of the GCC logic for this specific code: You're returning a reference, which is getting understood as placing an address into the return register. Therefore empty needs to be an object in runtime. It's declared as static, so it needs to have global lifetime even with local scope, no problem with that. The returned address needs to be that of the object, which is non-constexpr, but it's still getting treated as const, no problem with that. Done.
As mentioned in comments, it doesn't make sense to declare a constexpr non-trivial object. It needs to be initialized properly etc. For what you're asking, it's not a problem because constexpr gets "downgraded" to const for the object whose address you return. If you use it for more, e.g. a public member value, the compiler could still try to figure out what that constexpr-value is, disregarding the runtime object in that case. The problems start when you expect your GCC to produce faster or smaller code and it just doesn't and you can't force it. Solution: write const.
In short only things that can be constexpr will actually be constexpr and you should use sensible keywords.
Other compilers can take a different, less permissive approach and tell you that your code doesn't make sense, as you've seen - or fail to understand the contradiction and produce garbage, or anything else. In the end a compiler is just another code written by humans that tries to cover all cases, but can't do it perfectly.

The answer is non-sense. Almost every sentence is wrong.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
